Effect of FFT length on phase response
How does changing the fft length affect phase response? If the signal has a phase shift of 90 degrees, what would change in the phase response of the signal with increasing fft lengths? I'm not sure how to interpret the result of this Matlab code, when using different fftSizes:
clear all
close all
clc

% Generate a sample signal (e.g., a sine wave)
fs = 48000; % Sampling frequency in Hz
t = 0:1/fs:1-1/fs; % Time vector
f = 1000; % Frequency of the sine wave in Hz
signal = sin(2*pi*f*t + pi/2); % Sine wave signal with phase shift of 90 degrees

% Define the FFT size
fftSize = 4096;

% Compute the FFT of the signal
fftSignal = fft(signal, fftSize);

% Normalize the FFT output
normalizedFFT = fftSignal / max(abs(fftSignal));

% Compute the magnitude in dB
magnitudeInDB = 20 * log10(abs(normalizedFFT));

% Compute the phase in degrees
phaseInDegrees = angle(normalizedFFT) * (180 / pi);

% Plot the magnitude spectrum
frequencies = (0:fftSize-1) * (fs / fftSize); % Frequency vector
figure;
subplot(2, 1, 1);
plot(frequencies, magnitudeInDB);
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');
ylabel('Magnitude (dB)');
title('Magnitude Spectrum (Normalized to 0 dB)');
grid on;
xlim([0 fs/2]); % Show only the positive frequencies

% Plot the phase spectrum
subplot(2, 1, 2);
plot(frequencies, phaseInDegrees);
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');
ylabel('Phase (Degrees)');
title('Phase Spectrum');
grid on;
xlim([0 fs/2]); % Show only the positive frequencies

I see that for an fft size of 4096, the phase response at 1000 hz is not too different from that of size 16384.


2 things I'd like to understand:

The plots don't show a 90 degree phase shift, am I doing something wrong in my plot?

From a TESTING point of view, is there anything I should specifically look for when using a higher FFT size, to prove its working as expected. Less noise, higher slope for example.


Any help appreciated.

So, what exactly is the question? The phase plots seem very similar to me (which should be the case). Could you please clarify what you are trying to find out?

Updated, thanks.


The plots don't show a 90 degree phase shift, am I doing something wrong in my plot?

Why would they show a 90 degree phase shift? Shift against what refrence?
Your signal is a sine shifted by $-\pi/2$ which is simply a cosine. The continuous Fourier Transform of a cosine of frequency $\omega$ are two delta diracs at the frequencies $\pm \omega$ with a phase of 0. A sine would also have the same two amplitude diracs but with the phase of $-\pi/2$ at $+\omega$ and a phase of $+\pi/2$ at $-\omega$
If you had chosen a frequency that's and integer multiple of the DFT resolution you would have seen something similar. The amplitude would have two peaks at $\pm$ the signal frequency and zero every else. The phase would be zero at these peaks and undefined everywhere else. The phase would not change with FFT length at all (provided all FTT lengths involved meet the "integer multiple" condition".
Since your signal frequency is not an integer multiple of the DFT resolution you get an effect that's often referred to as "spectral leakage". In essence the DFT than is the sum of two phase shifted Dirichlet Kernels. In most cases the effects of FFT lengths on the phase response will be quite small.

Is phase unwrapping necessary here?

Nope. The phase jump is a real phase jump. Phase unwrapping only does something if the phase jumps by $2\pi$. Your jump is $\pi$

@Hilmar, we know when the phase jump is $\pi$ that it's equivalent to keeping the phase continuous and reversing polarity.  Like the sinc function, say in the frequency domain, when it changes signs, why not just change the sign on $|X[k]|$ instead of a jump discontinuity of $\pi$ in the phase?

The curious thing, though, is I expect shit to cross through zero when its polarity is reversed. That's surely not the case here.

@Hilmar could you clarify how the phase jump in my case is pi? Also in what case is a jump by 2pi is performed?
